# Is it true that every algorithm $f(x)\in{\mathcal O}(BB(n))$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Assuming there is an algorithm with the runtime $f(n)$. Define $BB(n)$ as the [BusyBeaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) function.

The algorithm must always returns the same output for the same input, but it might use some internal random (e.g. a random pivot selection of QuickSort) which might change the required calculation steps. The algorithm must halt for all inputs. Is the following statement true for all these algorithms?

$f(n)\in{\mathcal O}(BB(n))$?

I think it is true, because $BB(n)$ grows faster than every calculatable function, but I'm not sure if this is a good reason.

Thank you very much

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed, and due to the reason you say.

Let $M(n)$ be TM with runtime $f(n)$. Then it would be possible to build another machine $C$ which does the following:

- On input $n$, simulate $M(n)$ and for each step given by $M$ add $1$ to a counter.

Then $C(n)$ computes the runtime $f(n)$, and it certainly effectively computable.

Thus as $BB(n)$ asymptotically dominates every computable function, it must be the case that $f(n)\in \mathcal{O}(BB(n))$.

We have ignored the possible randomness, but to account for that we can restrict the analysis to the worst case running time, which is also computable (we can enumerate all possible paths that the algorithm may follow on input $n$, which are finite, since otherwise it would possibly not halt, then repeat the procedure for every path and output the max).

Comment: What for the following algorithm (which just ignores the input and does not generate a useful output): A random number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with the probability $P(X=n)=2^{-n}$ is generated and then the program just counts from zero to $2^n$. This algorithms always stops, but the expected runtime is $\infty$.

Comment: @KevinMeier Good observation. There is a subtlety concerning how the number is generated. If every number is possibly generated then we have to allow for the selection procedure to go on potentially forever. For example, a simple way to generate $n$ would be to flip a fair coin until a head comes up, then choose $n$ to be the number of flips. In this case it is easy to see that halting is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation:) Is it sufficient to define for the random source that it must have a finite entropy or is something else required?

Comment: @KevinMeier I am afraid I am not familiar with information theory so I cannot answer in those terms. The way I think of it is that the configuration graph of the TM computing the algorithm has to be finite, or otherwise I can always find a non-halting path since the fan out in Probabilistic TMs has to be finite. This last condition pretty much sounds like what you are saying that entropy must be finite, but then again I am out of my depth talking about entropy :)

Comment: I just played around and it seems that it only depends on the count of different values / symbols which could be returned by the random generator and not on the entropy. Thank you very much:)!

Comment: Doesn't counting from $0$ to $2^n$ with probability $2^{-n}$, as in your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1938248/is-it-true-that-every-algorithm-fx-in-mathcal-obbn#comment4058402_1975504), have expected runtime $1 + o(1)$, not $\infty$?  (Of course you could just count to $n 2^n$, or whatever, instead.)